# Add jsp page to CAS server

Tags: spring, jsp, cas, jasig

I'm newbie in using **CAS** and wanted to add a custom jsp page to the server after the login page and before it redirects to the client after successful login. I searched and thought that this would be done by adding the jsp page say Test.jsp in /WEB-INF/view/jsp/default/ui/Test.jsp and then changing the login-webflow.xml but i have little knowledge of Spring framework and failed in implementing using this technique as it redirected as usual, I wanted to know what all steps i'm missing or what would be the correct way to do it. Thanks in Advance.